# Adding tasks on taskqueue

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I have task queue that adds task to second queue, while second queue is paused. Is it possible to add task to task-queue which is paused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can add tasks to a paused queue.

**edit:**

I verified this by trying it on production app engine.

Comment: Thanks. I had a moment of clarity, when I realized that I was hitting CPU quota on production and had to pause one of task queues, so had t anticipate future steps :)